# How to import the Android App project source code in Eclipse?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout, android-manifest, android-source

I downloaded the android source code for callLog UI for the Contacts, Call log, and Dialer applications using this link https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts/

Now, I want to use it on eclipse. But when I try to import the project,it says it didnt found the project. Then I tried to set all the configurations manually, but it show a lot of errors with the importing, the AndroidManifest.xml, with the R.java, etc.

So is there any way of import this directly as a project to eclipse?

Thanks.

Comment: Please expand URL shortened link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import existing Android project into Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231474/how-to-import-existing-android-project-into-eclipse)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File->New Project ->Android Project

In the dialog, choose the option "Existing Project" and put the path to the project root path.
This always works for me.

Answer (score 3):

With adt-20131030 it's File-->New-->Project...-->Android-->Android Project from Existing Code. Then put the path to the project root path.