# How to Build android native dialer application (Kitkat version) in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea

how could we Build the android open source applications like Dialer, Calendar, Contacts in intellij idea or eclipse, for example if I imported the source code for a project (Dialer), what process should I follow to build the .apk file successfully.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. Do you want to import the apks or do you want to build them yourself?

Comment: I want to import the project source code and build it on my machine

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649420/how-to-import-the-android-source-code-in-eclipse): It describes where to get the files and how to import it properly.