# Eclipse not importing Android projects

Tags: java, android, eclipse, windows-7

I am trying to import the projects I made on other machine. So I copied the workspace folder from other machine into current PC and replaced the default workspace folder that was created when I installed fresh eclipse. After replacing workspace, when I try to import the projects from the workspace, I get error "Invalid Project description".

- What should I do to import all my projects in eclipse?
  Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify whether you are copying workspaces between the same versions of Eclipse? In my experience copying workspaces cross-versions doesn't work reliably.

Comment: yes they are the same version of eclipse

Comment: I installed fresh eclipse? you mean all android plugins also right.

Comment: This's duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231474/how-to-import-existing-android-project-into-eclipse

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found that when I try to import an existing project into my workspace, it only works if I select the `General->Existing Projects into Workspace`.  If I select `Android->Existing Android Code into workspace` then I have an issue where it doesn't import properly.

Maybe you are facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
 File >> New >> Android Project
```

Then choose:

```
 Create project from existing source
```

And put your project path

Answer (score 0):

OK try this, Zip your project folder. File->Import->General->Existing Projects into Workspace->Select archive file
or
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8431
[How to import existing Android project into Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231474/how-to-import-existing-android-project-into-eclipse)

Comment: OK try this, Zip your project folder. File->Import->General->Existing Projects into Workspace->Select archive file

Comment: Rajesh- don't copy and paste other people's solutions. Deep link, like this; http://stackoverflow.com/a/5450375/1348379

Comment: @OceanLife http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: I stand corrected. It appeared to me to be insufficiently referenced despite the original question (not suggested answer) being linked to. Hence my deep linking comment.

Answer (score 0):

File->Import->General->Existing Projects into workspace
This works perfectly. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone, if the above doesn't work for you, you may want to check that the .classpath and .project files are there. I had a similar experience where I was trying to import my project files' from my svn working copy. However, it shows up as a greyed out unselectable project. Copying .classpath and .project file from a local backup made it work.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue.

Eclips cannot import project if it is already exist in workspace. Double check if you already have a project with same name.