# android eclipse projects in package explorer disappears

Tags: android, eclipse, package-explorer

Hi I am having problems with the Eclipse for android development. 
After the computer is hanged I restarted again and open Eclipse the package Explorer shows nothing.

I tried to reboot computer / reboot Eclipse, but still fails

I then tried import back those app (say abc project) that beforehand developed but it says it duplicates the abc project that already exists. It appears that the package folder has actually something inside but the projects just appear invisible. How could that be repaired?

I have researched through the web but find no way out. It makes me headache...are there any method for repairing?

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: take one new project and check whether it is showing in the package explorer or not? and get back to me

Comment: Yes i have just created one.  It can be shown in the package explorer as the only one visible in the package explorer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the project inside the workspace but eclipse is not recognizing it. In this case, You'll have to re-import the project.

- Copy the code from the workspace through your windows explorer (or finder in mac) and paste it outside your workspace.
- Then import it again using the code you just pasted outside. Check "Copy projects into workspace" option while importing.
- Delete the code you copied outside the workspace.

  The project will be re-imported and there will only be one copy inside your workspace.

Also see:

[How to import existing Android project into Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231474/how-to-import-existing-android-project-into-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Try create another workspace and copy the projects there, then delete the older workspace and rename the created workspace. Should work.