# Importing Android project

Tags: android, import

I have sometimes problem when I import an Android project already existing... I have the errors :
"Project has no target set. Edit the project properties to set one."
"Parser exception for /projectName/AndroidManifest.xml: Premature end of file."
And all my files (.java, layout, manifest etc...) are empty !!!

Please tell me what is the exact way to import properly Android project.

Thanks,

N

Answer (score 1):

those answers should solve the problem, I suggest that you try cleaning the project and rebuilding it from project> clean and project>build project.
I hope that helps.

*if build project is unclickable, remove tick from build automatically, this will enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Try : 
File -> Import -> Android -> Existing Code

[image]

And Copy projects into workspace

Answer (score 0):

you have to put this into your mainfest

```
target=android-8
```

also check this out [How to import existing Android project into Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231474/how-to-import-existing-android-project-into-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

I also have this compilation error when I've tried to import projects into working set.
And what I've done - I realized that there has to be an empty Workspace when you try to Import projects.

So there is no need to put your projects into your Workspace. Just create an empty folder for Workspace and then Import. And really, I've read that William Kinaan recommended above.