# git eclipse pulls no project

Tags: android, eclipse, git, repository

I am new to working with repositories.
I'm forced to work with my team on academic project using git. My job is to write Android app.

The problem is when I wrote it, then pushed it to repo I want to pull it on different machine.
But when I pull it, I get only "source" files, no: (for example) `R.java`.
Moreover: I wanted to use "Clean project" Option, but it seems, that my Eclipse is not treating the pulled files as project (when I click "Clean..." I can choose any project in my workspace, but the download one is lacking).

Anyone could help me?

EDIT:
I've solved the problem:
Git doesn't push to repository automatic-generated files, like R.java. After you pull it back, you have to Clear project and rebuilt it. If it still doesn't work: try restarting Eclipse

Comment: my screen:
http://postimg.org/image/d3l4qol81/

Comment: Are you sure you pushed everything from the other machine? The root of the project in the workspace would have had several "." files.

Comment: I think you didn't import your project into eclipse:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231474/how-to-import-existing-android-project-into-eclipse

Comment: I've solved the problem. Added soluton to my post