# So many errors when trying to import source files into eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apk

I am completely inexperienced, and lately I have hired a contractor to develop an android app for me.

He sent me the source codes and the APK files, but I need to verify whether the source codes are legit, so I am trying to compile them and recreate the APK file.

So far I have installed eclipse, ADT Plugin, and did install the Java thing on my mac.

However when I finally manage to open the source codes up, there are many errors, and I don't know where I can compile it. I mean, is there a button I can click?

I have attached a picture of the errors.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfhwN.png

I read elsewhere that eclipse will automatically compile the APK file and save it in the bin folder. However there isn't any APK file in my case.

I am running on Mac Version 10.9.

Please help!!

Comment: Click on the "Problems" and you'll see exactly what the errors are. That will help you. You're likely missing some build dependencies.

Comment: You created a Java project, not an Android one. If your contractor sent you all the project, why don't you just import it in Eclipse ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231474/how-to-import-existing-android-project-into-eclipse

Comment: Right click your project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries and then make sure Android is in the list of included libraries. If not, click on Add Library > Android Classpath Container. If you're still getting the errors, click on the Android tab while still in Properties and make sure the Library is found.

Comment: From the look of it, your project doesn't recognise any Android classes, so I think you haven't installed the Android SDK

Comment: Can you please let me know the proper way of opening the source files in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have missed some of the jar files or library files.
Right click on Project in Eclipse, Properties on side bar select "Java Build Path" -> "Order and Export" tab. There you can see if any jar files are missing. delete if any and select the jar files from Workspace- project folder.

Comment: While this might be a decent approach for java in general, this is relatively poor advice for the specific problem of the question and is likely the start of a long and roundabout journey to resolution.  See ZouZou's explanation in comments for the root issue and easy fix.

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
I don't know what you mean by "if there are any jar files." I can't recognise it.
http://i.imgur.com/6c3375m.png