# How to copy my project so i two versions of it?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm making a timetable app and it'll have ads. But I'd like to copy the project into a new eclipse and make it the  "pro" version with extra features and no ads. How to do that?

Comment: If your project is far from being complete and you would still be working on it more than a month from now, it would be best to separate everything you can in a library project and have your two projects share the same code. That way, you don't have to bother making changes to two codebases and only have one to worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy and paste from the local directory (workspace)

Comment: Oh Ok ill have to try that again. If I save both the apps in the same area (I have a app folder on desktop) when I load eclipse it asks me where to find the project but their both in the same folder. How can I chnage that? Or do I simply need to make a folder for each one? Thanks

Comment: Make a folder for each one

Comment: Hello now I've tried it I open eclipse choose the folder where my app is and then it shows nothing. Like a new app. How can I load my app?

Comment: If this doesnt work then try something else: go inside eclipse and then copy paste the package and then change its name. See if that works for you

Comment: @user3195144 Anytime!

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the project from the eclipse using `ctrl+c` and paste there only using `ctrl+v`

It will create a same project with the same package name. Now change the package name with appropriate pro version name and remove the ads from it..

Simple..!!!

Hope it will help you..!!!

Comment: Oh Ok ill have to try that again. If I save both the apps in the same area (I have a app folder on desktop) when I load eclipse it asks me where to find the project but their both in the same folder. How can I chnage that? Or do I simply need to make a folder for each one? Thanks

Comment: It will ask you first to change the name of the project.. So eclipse will take care automatically for you..

Comment: Hello now I've tried it I open eclipse choose the folder where my app is and then it shows nothing. Like a new app. How can I load my app?

Comment: So have you also not load the application in android? First load your application that have advertisement in your eclipse..then follow the steps that I told you in the answer.

Comment: Follow this link to import your existing project in eclipse - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231474/how-to-import-existing-android-project-into-eclipse