# Importing android projects

Tags: android, eclipse, import, project

I use Eclipse with ADT installed. And I have never really been able to import projects.
The thing is, when I do what tutorials tell me to do, which is:

```
My files:
> Username
> > Downloads
> > > Apps
> > > > Project1
> > > > > AndroidManifest.xml
> > > > > res
> > > > > src
```

> - Click import
> - Existing android application
> - Select root directory
> - - I selected the folder ".../Username/Downloads/Apps"
> - Then select the projects you want and click next...

The problem is, the list of apps to import is empty after I select my path!

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is just selecting the folder containing th res and src subfolders, then use the option (checkbox) "Copy projects into workspace". Then finish

Comment: I didn't use the same names as the actual files above. But selecting Project1 didn't help either... =(

Comment: That's weird. Maybe this post can help you... [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231474/how-to-import-existing-android-project-into-eclipse)

Comment: Can't find anyone with the same problem. Most people seem to be getting error messages, but my projects don't show up =/