# How to create new "Android Project" in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, libgdx

I installed the android SDK and with it installed the needed tools:

- Android SDK Tools rev 22.6
- Android SDK Platform-Tools rev 19.0.2
- Android SDK Build-tools rev 18.1

Android 4.4.2 (API19)

- Documentation for Android SDK
- SDK Platform
- Samples for SDK
- ARM EABI v7a System Image
- Intel x86 Atom
- Google APIs (ARM System Image)
- Glass Development Kit Preview
- Sources for Android SDK

Extras
 - Android Support Library
 - Google USB Driver

I am following a tutorial and it does not clearly say anything about how to get a android project in eclipse, neither do any sources they just say click it. For all i know it should work by installing a default SDK package with the android manager. Btw, I am using Windows 7.

[image]
I did close and reopen eclipse.

Comment: If you have already a project then you need to import it by File->import-Android->Existing Android Code into Workspace. Or you can create your own project by File->New->Android Application Project

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to import existing Android project into Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231474/how-to-import-existing-android-project-into-eclipse)

Comment: @Sripathi There is no Android anywhere. Not in import and not under new.

Comment: Check that you are in Java Perspective. Because Other perspective like Java EE will not show you the ADT.

Comment: @sripathi Not in front of pc. But where can i find that? I anticipate that im unable to find that easy since im new to eclipse.

Comment: Go to window->open perspective->java

Comment: @Sripathi Yes it is on java, it's the default setting too.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you haven't installed the ADT plugin for Eclipse.  You can find this in Eclipse Marketplace, under "Help / Eclipse Marketplace"; search for "ADT" and choose to install "Android Development Tools for Eclipse" from the list.