# Error when import existing Android project into Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, xml, import, project

I tried to import a project to eclipse as like this 
link :  [How to import existing Android project into Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231474/how-to-import-existing-android-project-into-eclipse)
so when i try to open my imported files in eclipse it will appear this error message.what's the reason for that and how can i fix it.

[image]

Comment: Details please!!! (The button right next to Ok)

Comment: this may sound weird but restart your computer

Comment: when click Details button it will show same details which is in above.

Comment: if you are importing an android project wouldn't be better to select import-android-android existing project into workspace- differing from what is on the link question you asked?