# Which directory do I use to import this Java project?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have attached a screenshot and I'm trying to import this project into Eclipse but I do not know what directory to select. Here is a screen shot: 
[image]

In the image what directory do I select during import?

**UPDATE:**
I've selected the "app" folder and I get the message, "No projects are found to import",

[image]

Comment: Assuming you are importing an Android-Studio project into Eclipse. Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231474/how-to-import-existing-android-project-into-eclipse

Comment: Upon further research it looks like it may be an Android Studio project. I'm guessing it's not possible to install an Android Studio project into Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing Android Studio (based on IntelliJ) and creating a new project it looks like it's a IntelliJ / Android project not an Eclipse project (there was no .project file). It has the same structure as an IntelliJ project.