# Errors with importing Android project in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

We had someone develop an Android app for us and although I have all his project files I cannot seem to get rid of the many warnings and errors that appear after import his project.

I am not a Java programmer nor have I ever used Eclipse, so I'm running pretty blind here, but I need to fix a couple of bugs that I at least managed to find in the code.

The developer saved his workspace as well as the Eclipse exe and all the jar files in a folder structure.  What I have tried to so far is:

- Copied all his Windows folder structure onto my Windows machine
- Opened up the Kepler Eclipse exe in this folder structure
- Set the workspace to the existing "Workspace" folder in this structure
- Updated a bunch of .jar paths that were showing up as errors from his paths to my new paths (this resolved those errors)
- Installed API 19 in the SDK manager (and selectved it) in order to get rid of android-19 errors
- Added the Workspace default JRE in the Java Build Path section as there was none there and to try and get rid of the "Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.4. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment." warning that I suspect is related to the over 200 resolve type errors I am getting.

I've searched the forums to no avail.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Think you should try and find a guy with knowledge about at least java and eclipse. At best Android too. Then let him sit down and setup the environment. Almost impossible to do via Stackoverflow. If you do not know any, then perhaps give a guy from one of the freelancer pages remote access to do it.

Comment: Too broad / not enough information. I'd start with setting up a clean environment, then importing the project like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231474/how-to-import-existing-android-project-into-eclipse - your eclipse or workspace seems to be broken since J2SE-1.4 is in no version of android the proper environment (1.5 .. 1.7, typically 1.6).

Comment: I figured as much...it was worth a shot, thanks. I'll see if I can find anyone