# How to add an android library to an eclipse project without checking it out in the workspace?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a project that has multiple android libraries mentioned as dependencies. Is there a need to add all the libraries to Eclipse workspace for building the project? Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231474/how-to-import-existing-android-project-into-eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the absolute need to have them when compiling your android project. Otherwise you would get compile errors because of missing classes. You have two options here

1. Have the library project in your workspace and reference it (like you mentioned).
2. Create a `jar` from each of the library projects and add those to your application. This way you won't need the library project in your workspace.

It depends on the kind of library which way you should choose. If the library is changed often and you have direct access to the sources I would import the project. If you're afraid to lose the clarity in your workspace you can use working sets to hide the library projects.